# I can't access Post method even though I have configured spring security

Tags: java, spring, authentication

"I'm using Spring Security for authentication and authorization on my web application, and want to allow access to a POST method that doesn't require authentication. I've configured it, but it's still asking for authentication when call that method My code is like this, I have configured to allow access to /hi without requiring authentication:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/hello").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/hi").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers( "/authenticate").authenticated()              .and().formLogin()
                .and().logout()
                .and().build();
        
    }
```

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class loginController {
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/hi")
    public String hi() {
        return "hi";
    }
@PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public String authenticateAndGetToken(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest) {
        return jwtService.generateToken(authRequest.getUsername());
    }

}
```

Why am I still being asked for authentication when calling the POST /hi method? Is there a way to allow access to this POST method without requiring authentication? Thank you!"

i tried to access /hello and success but with /hi no, i am trying to be able to access /hi

Comment: How do you call you `/hi` end point ?
Try that `curl POST http://[URL]/hi`

Comment: thank you, i think my brower sent a request with Get instead Post for /hi, i solved it with postman :3

Comment: Browser always send `GET` when you provide just a URL.